# php, own little file manager instead of FTP. Good idea?

Tags: php, ftp, httprequest

Im planning to add file manager (very basic once) because I never used FTP functions, and it looks easier (FTP connection loses when scripts is done). I would simply use POST request (or what should I?) instead of FTP functions. Is it good idea? Anyone knows restrictions?

Comment: You need to better elaborate what your use case is. If you're looking for a very simple implementation, then a PHP solution is good enough. If it gets bigger, then you need FTP. For even bigger systems, you'll probably need FTP+control via PHP.

Comment: I wonder if Amazon once had the same idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see only FTP functions are to post and receive files.

What you need to do is add dynamic form where you can select multiple files and upload them to specific directory of your chose.

You will need to get all available directories and files in them, probably with some kind of recursive function. More optimal way is to get directories/files of current folder and when you click on folder it will get files/folder for it.

Can it be done - sure. Is it a good idea - no. People will have access for uploading malicious files, we are not talking about images here, php scripts, shell scripts, executable viruses and so on...

If you are doing this only for yourself, for file posting and receiving I suggest you to use FTP clients for that.

Comment: how big a data can be via _POST method?

Comment: As big as you want. Remember to set `max_post_size` in `php.ini` to your preferred max value. (by default it's 2mb)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it, but it's probably best to use a 3rd party tool, rather than to write your own.

- [PHP File Manager](http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/)
- [PHPfileNavigator2](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/index.php?opc=4&lg=ing)
- [FileManager](http://www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/filemanager/)
- ...

Keep in mind that both PHP and your webserver can put certain restrictions on the size of files that you can transfer, it is of course possible to change these in the configuration files.